# Solace - Message delivery count

Tags: jms, solace

We are using **Solace** as messaging broker. How can I get the number of times a message is delivered from broker? In **Jboss**, there is a property called `JMSXDeliveryCount`. Is there anything similar in **Solace**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solace JMS API is compliant with JMS1.1.
Unfortunately, JMSXDeliveryCount is an optional property in the JMS1.1 specification that is not implemented by the Solace JMS API.

For now, you can keep track of redelivered messages with JMSRedelivered, which does not provide the count.

If you are worried about application handling of "poisonous" messages - messages which cannot be consumed for some reason and need to be redelivered, you can make use of the "Max Redelivery" feature on the Solace endpoints. Messages will be moved to the Dead Message Queue or even configured to be discarded, when the message has been redelivered above the "Max Redelivery" count.

Support for JMSXDeliveryCount is in Solace's feature candidate list, and is likely to be implemented in a future release.

Comment: Update: This metric is now available:
https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Message-Properties.htm?Highlight=JMSXDeliveryCount#jms_delivery_count